# DataDog metric for Kubernetes PersistentVolume usage or remaining space

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, datadog, persistent-volumes

Is there a DataDog metric to report the space used or remaining in a GCP PersistentVolume. I have found disk use metrics for the container itself, but not for a PersistentVolume.

I am working in GoogleCloudPlatform.

Comment: you mean this? https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/data_collected/ --> `kubernetes_state.persistentvolumeclaim.request_storage` ?

Comment: @Vitalii That reports the PVC spec.resources.requests.storage value. I want to know how much of that value is used/remains.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer:

The metric `kubernetes.kubelet.volume.stats.used_bytes` will allow you to get the disk usage on PersistentVolumes. This can be achieved using the tag `persistentvolumeclaim` on this metric.

You can view this metric and tag combination in your account here: https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary?filter=kubernetes.kubelet.volume.stats.used_bytes&metric=kubernetes.kubelet.volume.stats.used_bytes

Documentation on this metric can be found here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/data_collected/#kubelet